# Windows XP repair install stalls

Tags: windows-xp, reinstall, windows-installer

I had a windows installation that was essentially non functional (RPC process terminating unexpectedly, which caused an automatic reboot, even in safe mode)  I brought out the XP install disk and attempted a repair install.  The text-mode phase completed successfully, but after rebooting into graphic mode it is stuck at "39 minutes"  Windows is running it's busy indicator and cycling features, but I don't see any hard drive activity.

I've run hardware diagnostics, scandisk, chkdsk, etc. and no errors were detected in either the system or the drive.

Update: After letting it run overnight, I get an error message:

> Error:
>   The signature for Windows XP Professional Upgrade is invalid.  The error code is 426.
>   The service has not been started.
>
> ---
>
> Fatal Error:
>   Setup failed to install the product catalogs.  This is a fatal error.  The setup log files should contain more information.
>
> ---

Comment: how long do you let it sit at the 39 minutes mark before you kill it off and reboot?

Comment: Be sure all extra devices are disconnected from the PC during the repair.

Answer (score 1):

We need to know how long you  let it set at the 39 minute hang as requested by BBlake, if you did not let it sit for a couple of hours, try that first, if no joy:

Similar issue described here, http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;828267

look at the setup log for clues.

> examine the Setup log files for anything that may indicate what may be causing the problem. To do this, press SHIFT+F10 to open a command prompt after the first restart, and after any subsequent restarts, if Setup stops responding. In the %windir% folder (typically, C:\Windows or C:Winnt), look for the Pnplog.txt file. This log file is only created during setup if there is an issue that is detected with hardware.

I would also run a memory tester
http://www.memtest.org/

Download the prebuilt ISO, burn it to CD as an Image (not data), boot from that CD and run the memory test for a couple of hours or overnight to stress test the memory. If you get errors with this test you have a bad memory module, if you have more than one memory module installed remove all but one and re-run the test, test each module individually until you find the bad one.

.

Comment: I ran the hardware diagnostics, which included a memory test, though I don't think it took several hours by itself, so it may not be as exhaustive.

Comment: There was no Pnplog.txt  Other logs indicated some unsigned dlls being registered, and catalog files that could not be removed.

Comment: I would back up the data and do a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue come through once before, and I was able to resolve by booting with the CD, and instead of doing the repair install, I went into the Recovery Console, and ran the following two commands, the next time I tried to do a repair install, it went off without a hitch.

```
chkdsk -r
```

Once this completed, I then ran

```
fixboot
```

Be careful with the 2nd one, if you are working in a multi-boot environment.

Comment: chkdsk (in recovery console, but not not full windows) halts at 50%, takes a very long time (I left it running over the weekend) and then reports `The volume appears to contain one or more unrecoverable problems.`